# How to navigate between Xamarin Android to Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, navigation

is there anyway to navigate from android and iOS specific activity to Xamarin forms Content page in PCL. I have tried nearly everything I could.

> SetPage(App.RetryOkPage(imagebytes))
>
> MessagingCenter
>
> LoadApplication(app) where app = new App();
>   and   app.MainPage =
>   new NavigationPage(new RetryOkPage(photoCropByte));

I am getting this error all the time. 
**'Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class '**

Comment: Can you clarify why do you want to do that?

Comment: Basically, I have made a custom renderer of camera and after clicking the picture i want to go back to forms page to show a user the image. I am sending the image as a byte array. I have done this to minimise platform specific code. I have tried above shown techniques.

Comment: @user1234, You want to create custom camera and display image when click image, I suggest you can take a look this sample:[Xamarin.Forms - View Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-view/)

Comment: This uses cameraApi and I have already created a Camera2Api and AVCam respectively for android and iOS as it gives a better picture quality and more functionalities. I can not navigate back to the forms as a navigation page.

Comment: @user1234 Can you post some code here? I can not know about Camera2Api and AVCam, and can not reproduce your project at my side.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I solved it using messaging center. I was making a mistake using messaging center but it has been solved. Thank you for your help.